# how can i set this background on my texts

Tags: android, android-studio

i found some apps(mostly chatting apps) have a special text background, like this :http://puu.sh/qKlgX/0c95be7545.jpg
my question is obvious , how can i do this so?
thank you

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: Create a 9 patch image and set the background of the that TextView, it will decrease and increase the size accordingly and work like you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following but **note**, without the **arrow**:

1- **shape_chat_message.xml** inside your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eda349"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

2- **your_layout.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_chat_message"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_message_body"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use

```
myTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.your_image.png);
```

I think this might work, i usually use this for my apps and their backgrounds.

Hope this helps!